# How to pass any Codable Struct as a return from function and use it in JSONEncoder

Tags: swift, generics, codable

As part of network request I want to pass any `struct` that is `Codable` into `JSONEncoder().encode` function. When I pass object directly , lets say

```
struct MyObject: Codable {}
 func createData<T:Codable>(objectToEncode: T) {
       JSONEncoder().encode(T)
       }
 func assigningObject() {
        createData(objectToEncode: MyObject())
         }
```

it works perfectly, however I do not know how to pass any codable object that is output of a function, when I call lets say :

```
 func createObject() -> Codable {
      return MyObject()
     }
    
 func assigningObject() {
       let myReturnObject = createObject()
       createData(objectToEncode: myReturnObject)
       }
```

I am not able to do  `createData(objectToEncode: myReturnObject)` , because compiler is showing error `Value of protocol type 'Codable' (aka 'Decodable & Encodable') cannot conform to 'Decodable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols`

Is there any way how to return struct object from function that will work ?

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what you are trying to do, but you could either make `createObject` a generic function or perhaps use an opaque type. You can't declare a function to return a protocol since Swift needs to infer the concrete type.

Comment: I don't know whether this will work in your real code, but try `func createObject() -> some Codable`.

Comment: @Sweeper yes, adding "some" keyword helps ! However some is only supported from iOS 13 , and my project minimum deployment is 12.1 . So I only need to find now how to make these opaque type in ios 12. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for iOS 13 and newer is using opaque type :

```
func createObject() -> some Codable
```